# Changing data type of a column containing data in Oracle db

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes, alter

I am using Oracle 19c.
I have a table,which I need to change the data-type of one of its columns:

- from number to number (24,8)

The column contains data, nearly 300.000 records and I am required to keep the data.

If I do this without truncating/deleting data:

1. Does it harm data integrity?
2. Does it effect the datatype of existing data?

The reason for this operation is that the column should have had 7 or 8 decimals but it has been limited to 4 decimal somehow, even though data type is number.  Either my etl tool (informatica ) or oracle db has limited, I do not know.

thanks in advance

Comment: `number` is a less strict datatype than `number(24, 8)`, you cannot perform such modification with `alter table`. If you have something that truncates a number it may be easier to adjust the datatype mapping on the reader/writer side.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't appear to be with Oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
 num NUMBER 
);

INSERT INTO T1 (num) VALUES (123.12345678);


SELECT * FROM T1;
NUM
123.12345678
```

Comment: probably, Im missing sth in either in my query, or in informatica.